# Can someone help me prove this statement by induction or some other proof method?

Tags: summation, induction

Show that $3n < 2^n$ for all integers $n \ge 4$.
 I have tried for base $n=5$: then obviously $p(5)$ is true as
$$
3\cdot 5 < 2^5 . 
$$
Now since $p(x)$ is right I have tried to prove $p(x+1)$ by using it: substituting in the general relation I hope to get
$$
3(n+1) < 2^{n+1}
$$
but at this point I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your base needs to be case with $n=4$ as you need to prove for $n\geq 4$.
As for step, you need to show that $3n < 2^n \Rightarrow 3(n+1) < 2^{n+1}$, so you need to use $3n<2^n$

Comment: yeah sorry base for 4. But after when i come to 3n+3 < 2*2^n , how should i continue

Comment: do i write it as 3n + 3 < 2^n + 2^n